# How to store images into Firebase directly, without coding (or the easiest way) And without creating an application that would do so?

Tags: json, database, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

How can i store images in firebase directly without coding? (using the firebase website)? All tutorials are talking about how to create an app or website which would "upload" and "retrieve" images using java(android studio). but thats not what i am looking for.

edit:
I am a beginner to Android. So Any recommendation for the tutorial on this issue would be great. But the tutorial must be easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the Firebase console to upload and download images from Cloud Storage.

https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/storage/

Comment: can you kindly recommend an simple, short an easy tutorial that teaches this?

Comment: Recommendations for offsite resources are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The best place for storing images,videos and audio files is firebase cloud storage. Go to the console and look for cloud storage and you should be able to create folders and upload images from there without using any code.

Comment: can you kindly recommend an simple, short an easy tutorial that teaches this?